# pyspark sql sum vs aggr

Tags: apache-spark-sql, aggregation, pyspark

Which of the following is the better way in Pyspark? 
Does the second query has any advantage/performance gain over first query in PySpark (in cluster mode)?

```
    #1) without using aggr
    total_distance_df = spark.sql("SELECT sum(distance) FROM flights")\
        .withColumnRenamed('sum(CAST(distance AS DOUBLE))', 'total_distance')
    total_distance_df.show()

    Vs

    #2) with using aggr
    total_distance_df = spark.sql("SELECT distance FROM flights")\
                             .agg({"distance":"sum"})\
                             .withColumnRenamed("sum(distance)","total_distance")
    total_distance_df.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are same, Check the **`explain`** plan on the queries to see any differences.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample df
 df1.show()
+---+--------+
| id|distance|
+---+--------+
|  a|       1|
|  b|       2|
+---+--------+

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")

spark.sql("SELECT sum(distance) FROM tmp").withColumnRenamed('sum(CAST(distance AS DOUBLE))', 'total_distance').explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[sum(distance#179L)])
#+- Exchange SinglePartition
#   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_sum(distance#179L)])
#      +- *(1) Project [distance#179L]
#         +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#178,distance#179L]

spark.sql("SELECT distance FROM tmp").agg({"distance":"sum"}).explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[sum(distance#179L)])
#+- Exchange SinglePartition
#   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_sum(distance#179L)])
#      +- *(1) Project [distance#179L]
#         +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#178,distance#179L]
```

As you can see plans are similar for both SUM and aggr.

Comment: Just want to know which one is better. I thought both have a different purpose. explain() is some thing new I learnt from your reply.